# Quick fix (CTRL+1) in Flash Builder 4

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flexbuilder, flash-builder, fdt

What is the purpose of quick fix in Flash Builder 4? I have tried using it to auto create event listener functions, class methods or properties, local variables etc but none of these work. Does this functionality only exist in FDT? If so what does quick fix do in FB4?

For example:

```
myEventDispatcher.addEventListener(SomeEvent.EVENT_TYPE, myEventHandlerFunction);
```

Using FDT, I would highlight "myEventHandlerFunction", press CTRL+1 and a menu appears with several fix options, the first being *create event listener "myEventHandlerFunction" in class "MyClass"*

However in FB4 pressing CTRL+1 or even selecting quick fix from the right click menu doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is an FDT only Feature! 
It's one of the biggest reasons for me to use FDT over any other tool. Quick Fixes rock!!

Comment: I wouldn't say this is FDT only. Flash Develop has had this feature for years (although it's CTRL + SHIFT + 1 in FD).